# React Router with dynamic path and dynamic component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm building the app with hierarchical structure and ability to set any slug url the user  wants by the admin panel. For example, if the top page has url `news` and the page inside has url `new_telescope`, the whole url would be `/news/new_telescope/`. I wrote the url controller to handle this, so it really doesn't matter how many levels are there in the url - I get the data of the needed page from the server. So my `React Router` wouldn't have predefined urls - I need to take the current url, send it to server, get the data, get the component and render it. Now it looks like this:

```
function getRoute() {
    url.splice(0, 1);
    adminRequest(
        'get',
        constants.SERVER_ADDRESS + `/system/url/?url=` + JSON.stringify(url) + '&version=1',
    ).then(response => {
        const CurrentComponent = lazy(() => import('./' + response.data.template));
        return <Route path={window.location.pathname} element={<CurrentComponent page={response.data}/> } />
    });
}

return (
    <>
        <Suspense fallback={<div className='preloader'><CircularProgress size='75px' /></div>}>
            <Routes>
                // trying to get the current url with proper component
                { getRoute() }
                <Route path="/admin/" element={<Admin />} />
                <Route path="/admin/login/" element={<Login />} />
                ...
            </Routes>
        </Suspense>
    </>
);
```

So the problem is with the `getRoute` function. As you can see I make a request, get the component name from the DB and use `lazy` to import it. In that function I make a new `Route` to put it to `Routes`. But I get errors `No routes matched location` with any url. And of course the component doesn't render. I thought that `Suspense` will wait for the first route to appear but it doesn't work that way. How can I make a `Router` to wait for a dynamic route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

1. The `getRoute` function doesn't return anything. Sure, the Promise chain started from `adminRequest` returns some JSX, but that resolved value isn't returned by the other function.
2. React render functions are 100% synchronous functions. You can't call an asynchronous function and expect React to wait for any asynchronous code to resolve to render any content.

## Solution

Use a `useEffect` hook to issue the side-effect of fetching the route. Unconditionally render the `Route` but conditionally render the `element` value.

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
const [CurrentComponent, setCurrentComponent] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  const getRoute = async () => {
    url.splice(0, 1);
    const response = await adminRequest(
      "get",
      constants.SERVER_ADDRESS +
        `/system/url/?url=` +
        JSON.stringify(url) +
        "&version=1"
    );
    
    const CurrentComponent = lazy(() =>
      import("./" + response.data.template)
    );
    
    setData(response.data);
    setCurrentComponent(CurrentComponent);
  };

  getRoute();
}, [url]);

...

<Suspense fallback={<div className="preloader">Loading...</div>}>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path={/* whatever the path is */}
      element={CurrentComponent ? <CurrentComponent page={data} /> : null}
    />
    <Route path="/admin/" element={<Admin />} />
    <Route path="/admin/login/" element={<Login />} />
  </Routes>
</Suspense>
```

Demo

[image: Edit react-router-with-dynamic-path-and-dynamic-component]